# Как спарсить html

Tags: c#, html, парсер

Нужно парсить хтмл каждые пол секунды , как парсинг  сделать максимально быстрым и кратким ? Пробовал много баблов , использовал регекс  - нифига 
Хтмл спарсить между тегами .
Парсер будет многопоточен , тк это ускорит действие .

Comment: Цель какая? Что нужно достать? Не является ли он XHTML? Ну и работать двумя потоками. Один скачивает, второй парсит

Comment: по моему, многое зависит от библиотеки и от скорости инета. Сколько времени занимает полная загрузка страницы ? можно все рассчитать, что бы получилось наиболее оптимально

Comment: да и приведите ваш код, мб его осталось совсем немного допилить, что бы не писать все заново

Comment: приведите ваш код и ответь на вопрос

Comment: Нужен код для парсинга  от профи , мб я тупой (да) .

Comment: Ну раз от профи, то тогда так [mcve]